# Error: Parse error on ":" (COLON) at [2, 10] GraphQL при запросе в javascript

Tags: javascript, gitlab, graphql

Пробую  работать с graphQl gitlab через CURL там все нормально и результат возвращается, имя текущего пользователя.

```
GRAPHQL_TOKEN=a-s8AxjN2Nes4uxcdfnF
curl 'http://192.168.0.102:8007/api/graphql' \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $GRAPHQL_TOKEN" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST --data "{\"query\": \"query {currentUser {name}}\"}"
```

Но когда попробовал подключить через javascript библиотеку graphql-request то выводит ошибку:

```
const endpoint = 'http://192.168.0.102:8007/api/graphql';
    
  const graphQLClient = new GraphQLClient(endpoint, {
    headers: {
      authorization: 'Bearer a-s8AxjN2Nes4uxcdfnF',
    },
  });

  const query = `
    query: 'query {currentUser {name}}'
  `;

  graphQLClient.request(query).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('err=', err);
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Возникает ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как понять что не так в синтаксисе запроса (переменная query)?

Comment: поробуйте так const query = {query: "query {currentUser {name}}"}
  `;

Comment: Все равно ошибка: 
`R40_BY_CONTRACTORS_DASHBOARD.js:27 Error: Parse error on "query {currentUser {name}}" (STRING) at [1, 9]: {"response":{"errors":[{"message":"Parse error on \"query {currentUser {name}}\" (STRING) at [1, 9]","locations":[{"line":1,"column":9}]}],"status":200},"request":{"query":"{query: \"query {currentUser {name}}\"} "}}
    at GraphQLClient.<anonymous> (index.js:25)
    at step (index.js:25)
    at Object.next (index.js:25)
    at fulfilled (index.js:25)
    at meteor.js?hash=6d285d84547b3dad9717a7c89c664b61b45ea3d8:1117`

Comment: а так query = "{currentUser {name}}"

Comment: получилось через 
= 'query {currentUser {name}}'

Comment: оформить ответ?